Can I replace a 3-lead single coil transformer with an isolated type and tie p and s neutrals
The circuit I need to power has a 120vac side, powered straight from mains, and a 48vac side, previously provided by a 3-lead autotransformer. These two mutually exclusive paths to the rectifier diodes share a common neutral on the board.
Can I replace that transformer with a 48v center-tapped step-down transformer, using the two outside secondary leads and tying one of them to the neutral of the 120v primary? And if so, does it matter which side of the secondary coil I tie to that shared neutral?

Yes that will work. If all you are feeding is rectifiers the phase relationship beteen the 120V AC and 48V AC will not matter. This means it will not matter which way round you connect the 48V.
